# Getting Error for custom SOAP API for Magento2 failed to load external entity

Tags: magento2, soap-api-v1

I have followed this link https://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-custom-api/ but getting error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://127.0.0.1/m232/soap/default?wsdl&services=inchoHelloV1' : failed to load external entity "http://127.0.0.1/m232/soap/default?wsdl&services=incho
HelloV1" in E:\xampp\htdocs\m232\vendor\zendframework\zend-soap\src\Client\Common.php:33 Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\m232\vendor\zendframework\zend-soap\src\Client\Common.php(33): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://127.0.0....', Array) #1 E:\xampp\htdocs\m232\vendor\zendframework\zend-soap\src\Client.php(1070): Zend\Soap\Client\Common->__construct(Array, 'http://127.0.0....', Array) #2 E:\xampp\htdocs\m232\vendor\zendframework\zend-soap\src\Client.php(1245): Zend\Soap\Client->initSoapClientObject() #3 E:\xampp\htdocs\m232\vendor\zendframework\zend-soap\src\Client.php(1156): Zend\Soap\Client->getSoapClient() #4 E:\xampp\htdocs\m232\testapi1.php(32): Zend\Soap\Client->__call('softwebCustomap...', Array) #5 {main} thrown in E:\xampp\htdocs\m232\vendor\zendframework\zend-soap\src\Client\Common.php on line 33
```